# NHibernate connection string containing Provider

Tags: nhibernate

i've crrently got a problem where our applications are using NHibernate implementations where some older parts still use ADO. The problemn i'm having is that ADO requires a provider to be specified in order to work.

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=XX.XXX.XX.XX;Password=XXXXX;
```

Like so, how ever when i configure NHibernate to use the same connection string i get the following error:

```
Keyword not supported: 'provider'.
```

If i remove the provider from the connectionstring all is fine for NHibernate. Now i could just use two connectionstrings but i don't want to do that.

Is there a way to achieve this without having to make two connectionstrings, or fix some flaw in NHibernate?

Greetings,

F.B. ten Kate

Comment: Since i didn't specify, the old legacy stuff uses ADODB.Connection. If it would use SqlConnection i wouldn't have this problem, how ever i can't simply change the connection due to the different ways of handling transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, i figured out i could change the NHibernate driver_class to get things working, changed it to:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OleDbDriver</property>
```

from

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
```

Not sure about any performance hits i might take from this but atleast it functions like this.